# WSO2 IS : How to configure when logout from SP, it will logout from WSO2 IS

Tags: wso2, logout, wso2-identity-server

I would like to configure when an user logout from SP then it will logout from WSO2 IS also. How can I configure for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use IDP initiated saml sso to fulfill your requirment.You can refer this [blog](http://xacmlinfo.org/2014/12/08/idp-initiated-saml2-sso-with-identity-server/) to get more details about IDP initiated SSO

To enable IDP initiated SSO, you have to enable "Enable IDP initiated SSO" check box under SAML service provider configuration.

Logout request should be as follow

`https://localhost:9443/samlsso?slo=true`

When IS received the logout request, Identity server send logout request to all the service providers in the session and will redirect to the `https://<IS_SERVER>:9443/authenticationendpoint/samlsso_logout.do`. Its a default logout page of Identity server.

You can IDP initiated SSO logout with `WSO2 Identity server + service pack2.`